# Replace Whitespace before Brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to learn regular expressions and I would like all whitespaces before the open parenthesis to be replaced with an underscore using Notepad++ regular expression search and replace.

Currently, my regular expression only replaces a space if it is immediately before the open parenthesis.

Before: `FIRST MIDDLE LAST("   ", " ")`

Expected: `FIRST_MIDDLE_LAST("   ", " ")`

My attempted regular expression: `\s+(?=\()`

`\s+` matches one or more white spaces
`(?=\()` is a positive look ahead using `\(` (open parenthesis) as the character.

Can anyone please explain what the correct regular expression should be? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess `\s+(?=[^()]*\()`

Comment: @thg435 has the answer, use http://regex101.com/ to test. Possible correction is `\s+(?=[^(]*\()` as we are only looking for an opening parenthesis.

Comment: @Rossiar: no, I think `[^()]` is better, `[^(]` will convert `foo )bar(` to `foo_)bar(` - doesn't look right!

Comment: @thg435 Thanks, this regular expression works and makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly this should work for you:

Find `\b\s+(?=.*?\()`  Replace: `_`

ie. all whitespaces following a word boundary, which is again followed by, but not a part of the selection, a couple of characters until the first occurrence of a opening bracket.